# Midpoint Approximation for Integral

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

My brother had this question for a homework assignment in calculus. The question speaks for itself and seems easy enough to solve. However, it seems that the midpoint approximation here is incorrect. My understanding is that midpoint approximation is the average of the lower and upper approximations, but the answers presented in these examples do not hold true with that. 
I chose these examples specifically because they only differ in two values (both of which are the larger in the second example), and have the same solution for the midpoint approximation.
What I am asking for is either an explanation of what we've been doing wrong or, in the case that the system is wrong, a method to find its solution rather than our own. Thanks all

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: It seems that they gave you the rate and ask for the quantities. It is then a problem of integration using the trapezoidal method as mentioned by coffeemath. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method

Comment: Have you arrived at the same solution with this method? I tried the trapezoid rule but I had a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average of the left and right endpoint estimates, sometimes called $L_n$ and $R_n$ respectively, is actually the same as the trapezoid estimate, called sometimes $T_n$, which is based on drawing trapezoidal slabs based on the values of the function at the two endpoints.

One would not expect the midpoint rule $M_n$ to agree in general with any of the above, since it uses sample values of the function at the midpoints of the subintervals, and those values are independent (in general) of the values of the function at the endpoints of the subintervals.

ADDED: I see now what they did in the "midpoint rule" calculation. For it they actually used *three* intervals of length $2$, so that the values at the midpoints are actually on the table of values given, and are (from left to right) the numbers $8,38,56$ with a sum of $102$, which must be multiplied by the subinterval length of $2$ to get the answer of $204$ as stated in the printout. (By the way I had to zoom in a bit to see that.)

Comment: Thanks, I must have confused those two. I'm still not clear on it though. If the approximation is independent of the values then how is there an answer?

Comment: For each function, you can do both calculations. What I'm saying is that the result of left/right calculations makes it unnecessary to do the trapezoid since it's the average, but to do the midpoint approximation one has to "start all over" and use the values of $f(x)$ at the midpoints. For example if the interval is $[0,4]$ with $n=2$ then $L_2$ uses $f(0),f(2)$ while $R_2$ uses $f(2),f(4).$ On the other hand $M_2$ uses $f(1),f(3),$ which may have nothing to do with the values of any of $f(0),f(2),f(4).$

Comment: In the questions, I am not given the values for r(1/2), r(3/2)... So I'm still uncertain of how they arrived at the answer 204. If I estimate that r(1/2) =~ (r(0) + r(1))/2 then I am getting precisely the trapezoid rule. So again, maybe I am missing something. In that case, if you understand something I don't, could you please demonstrate on one of these problems? It would be very helpful.

Comment: I have added a part to the answer. What they did for midpoint approximation is to use half as many intervals, so that the values at the relevant midpoints are in the given table. This is actually a common way to do approximations using table values.

Comment: Ok, I see now. That is correct. Btw, you can always drag and drop the image into a new tab for the correct size. Cheers